# Getting wrong measurements on my Kossel Linear Plus after installing SKR 1.3 with Marlin 2.0

Tags: marlin, delta, kossel, skr-v1.3

So I've switched the Trigorilla board in the printer with a SKR 1.3 with TMC2208 drivers and installed the latest Marlin 2.0, with a config based on [this one](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:3741425/). You can find the [Configuration.h here](https://pastebin.com/ij1G5tSw), the only thing I changed in Configuration_adv.h was the pin of the hotend fan.

Now when let the printer autocalibrate the delta settings, it tells me that the height is 141.35 mm, instead of the actual ~300 mm and I had to set the radius to 78 mm, instead of the actual 115 mm so that it doesn't try to probe outside the bed.

What settings could I have set so horribly wrong that I get these results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the problem was that the TMC2208 were wired for UART mode, yet Marlin was configured for standalone, which apparently makes them work, but with completely wrong step sizes. Changing it in the configuration completely eliminated the problem

Answer (score 2):

I would check the "steps per distance" setting.  If the motors were moving more than the firmware thinks, the height would measure as shorter than actual (since the number of steps would be less than the firmware expected).  Similarly, the radius would scale up.

You replaced the controller and motor drivers, so perhaps the micro-stepping is different.

If the result is inconsistently wrong, it could be a dynamics setting, such as acceleration or max velocity.

Comment: I thought the same, but I found the error: I had wired the TMC2208 for UART mode, but used TMC2208_Standalone in the firmware: It now uses the correct dimensions after using the right value in the configuration file

Comment: @Metalfreak Can you move this to an answer and then accept it once available? This could potentially help someone in the future and comments are not guaranteed to stick around